# How to only display one flyout at a time with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, nav, flyout

Can someone tell me how to update my code so whenever I hover over another LI a flyout that was displayed for a different main nav link will disappear right away and the other will appear? (I only want one flyout to appear at any given time)

Here's a working example on jsfiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/zoolander/YAfDL/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/YAfDL/10/

Added a "global" slide-up event on the hover action... Works?